# How do I subdivide a mesh into triangles?

Tags: modeling

Let's say I have a simple plane, and I want to add 4 faces to it but I'd like the subdivision to make triangles.

So instead of this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the face and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to [poke faces](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Usability_tools#Modeling):

[image]

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Usability_tools#Modeling):

> Poke Face, This tool fan-fills each face around a central vertex (r55833).
>
> This can be useful as a way to triangulate ngons, or the depth value can be used to make spikes or depressions, Access from the face menu or AltP.

Comment: Omg, seriously I was going to use poke or pinch to describe what I was trying to do. Is there a way to change subdivide to use triangles instead of quads though?

Comment: @jacobsd No. You *can* change the way corners are triangulated when using *Subdivide*, but otherwise no.