# Can a circle be filled with a triangle fan?

Tags: modeling

When a cylinder is added to a scene *Triangle Fan* fill type for the cap is provided in the last operator panel.

[image]

Is there any tool to use with a circle to fill it like triangle fan would do?

[image]

The alternatives *Grid Fill* and <kbd>F</kbd> (n-gon) can't be used when the vertex in the center of the circle is required.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads/14580#14580

Comment: When you create it, you can go to the Operator panel, and select Triangle Fan for the fill type

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5946/599

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Create and poke face

You can do this with 2 operations.

<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

- <kbd>F</kbd> (creates a face)
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (poke face, creating a triangle fan)

See: Mesh -> Face menu for both.

**Note for Blender 2.80 users:** Shortcut for Poke Faces was removed and the menu entry relocated to Face -> Poke Faces.

### Extrude and merge edges

<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>

- <kbd>E</kbd> (Extrude)
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (Merge)

  - <kbd>A</kbd> (Menu accelerator for the  *A̲t Center* option)

Note:

- Create face & Poke will assign UV's & vertex colors from surrounding faces *(the extrude method will simply extend UV's/colors, which may not be what you want)*.
- Poke uses a more advanced method to calculate the face center point
  (noticeable when edges aren't evenly spaced).