# How can I fill a cylinder cap?

Tags: modeling

Dumb question. I can't figure out how to make a mesh (quads or triangles like a pie) automatically so to this flat face so I can then pull the center to round it out (like half a sphere would look). I don't want to bevel it. Isn't there like some Hot Key combo that does this? 
[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15068/can-a-circle-be-filled-with-a-triangle-fan and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Triangles

As @ideasman42 points out in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15069/3078), you can press:

> <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
>
> - <kbd>F</kbd> (creates a face)
> - <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (poke face, creating a triangle fan)

## Quads

As @David said in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14580/3078), you can use grid fill by:

- Using <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] Right Click</kbd>, to select the edges
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and then selecting *Grid Fill* (can be done by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> after the previous combination)

Answer (score 7):

Delete the face > Select the vertices > Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude then Left mouse click > Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select collapse.

The better way would be to Delete the face > Select the vertices > Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude > Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale. Scale it way down > Left mouse click > Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select 'collapse'. Then hover your mouse over the larger part of the new face and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and scroll your mouse wheel to add a bunch of loop cuts and Left click when satisfied. This will make it easier to accomplish your half dome.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cylinder. Select the top face and delete face. Select all the edge vertices. Press  <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude followed immediately by  <kbd>S</kbd> to Scale and Zero, i.e.  <kbd>E</kbd>,  <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>0</kbd>.

To remove any duplicated vertices *Mesh >  Clean Up > By Distance* with  <kbd>M</kbd>,  <kbd>B</kbd>.